# htaccess allow,deny rules behaving strangely

Tags: apache, .htaccess, spam-prevention

Long story short, I have a list of IP addresses I want to completely ban from accessing my site. When I configure my htaccess file like this...

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 123.456.789.012
deny from 123.456.789.013
[etc...]
```

...it doesn't work. Those IP addresses are still able to hammer my site. But when I comment out the "allow from all"...

```
order allow,deny
#allow from all
deny from 123.456.789.012
deny from 123.456.789.013
[etc...]
```

...then it works, in that I can see that NO ONE is able to access my site, and the traffic quickly drops to zero. The problem is, I only want to block those IP addresses, not everyone. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order, so allow from all is at the end.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.456.789.012
deny from 123.456.789.013
allow from all
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Don't know why I thought the "allow from all" had to be at the top, but your solution did the trick.